# PHP Login Script Minor Issue

Tags: php, login-script

so I've constructed a simple login script for a website using PHP. It has worked fine, but I've made some recent changes to it that seem to stop it from functioning properly.

Basically when I'm putting the table into an array, I use the variable $y to keep track of the 'type' of user that is logging in. However when the log in is successful, upon echoing $y and $type they both return 0. A user can either be type 0 or type 1, but it seems $y is not being assigned for some reason when the user is found.

To confirm, the login statements etc do work, if the username and password is correct it displays the correct username and relevant details. At the moment it just doesn't seem to want to assign a value to $y for some reason.

```
// If statement that seems to be giving me trouble
global $arrayofdata;
$arrayofdata = array();

$n = 0;
$y = 0;

// Put tables into an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
// If statement to find position of username in array
if($arrayofdata[$n]['username'] == $username){
$y = $n;}
$arrayofdata[$n] = $row;
$n++;
}

// FULL CODE BENEATH HERE

<?php
session_start(); ?>
<html>

<head>
<title>:: clubb3r ::</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    loginscript::login();

class loginscript {

    // Login function.. 
    static function login() {

    $host = "gcdsrv.com";
    global $username;
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];}
    else{
    $username = $_POST[uname];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;} // Store username for later

    if(isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];}
    else{
    $password = $_POST[pword];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;} // Store password for later

    $connect = mysql_connect("gcdsrv.com", "", "");

    if(!$connect) {
    echo    "<h1>500 Server Error</h1>";
    }

    $db_select = mysql_select_db("c2h5oh_database", $connect);

    $resource = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, type, picture, rating FROM accounts;");

    global $arrayofdata;
    $arrayofdata = array();

    $n = 0;
    $y = 0;

    // Put tables into an array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
    // If statement to find position of username in array
    if($arrayofdata[$n]['username'] == $username){
    $y = $n;}
    $arrayofdata[$n] = $row;
    $n++;
    }

    $n = 0;

    // Set user type (normal user or bar/club, 0 for user and 1 for bar/club)
    if(isset($_SESSION['type'])){
    $type = $_SESSION['type'];}
    else{
    $type = $arrayofdata[$y]['type'];
    $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
    }

    // Counts entries
    $count = count($arrayofdata);
    global $count2; 

    // Login check loop, searches array for username and password in POST, also stores balance of that user for later
    for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
        if($username == $arrayofdata[$x]['username'] && $password == $arrayofdata[$x]['password'] && $username != "" && $password != "") {
            $z = 1;
        }

    }

        // Fail
        if($z != 1) {
        echo    "<h1>Bad Username or Password</h1><br />";
        echo    "<h1><a href='logout.php'>Try Again</a></h1>";
        }

        // Success
        // If for user success
        if($z == 1 && $type == 0) {
        echo    "<h1>Login Successful!</h1><br />";
        echo    "<h1><a href='mainuser.html'>Proceed</a></h1>";
        echo    $type;
        echo    $y;
        }

        //Success
        //If for bar/club success
        if($z == 1 && $type == 1){
        echo    "<h1>Login Successful!</h1><br />";
        echo    "<h1><a href='mainbar.html'>Proceed</a></h1>";
        echo    $type;
        }

    }

}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Shouldn't your $arrayofdata[$n] = $row; be inside the closing } if the condition is true?

Comment: My question would be, why is $y always 0 if I find the right username at $n = 5

Mr Techie I think you might be onto something, I haven't put the $row into the array yet so the 'username' point of the array doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Solution was;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
            $arrayofdata[$n] = $row;
        if($arrayofdata[$n]['username'] == $username){
        $y = $n;}
        $n++;
        }

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I see, you have two lines, that set `$y`.

```
`$y = 0;`
```

and

```
// Put tables into an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
  // If statement to find position of username in array
  if($arrayofdata[$n]['username'] == $username){
    $y = $n;
  }
  $arrayofdata[$n] = $row;
  $n++;
}
```

Looking further you see this three lines:

```
$arrayofdata = array(); //create EMPTY array
[...]
if($arrayofdata[$n]['username'] == $username){ //check index $n
[...]
$arrayofdata[$n] = $row; //set index $n
```

You access `$arrayofdata[$n]` before you set it. I guess your if-statement throws a PHP-Warning, control your logs ;)
You set `$y = $n` in the code that follows if your `if`-statement is true. As `$arrayofdata[$n]` doesn't exist, the if-clause if always false and `$y` stays 0.

Comment: Yep exactly this! Such a silly mistake on my behalf, thank you :)